# Yammer API issue - get groups showing error

Tags: javascript, api, sdk, yammer

I am integrating yammer features in our app (web-front-end stack and using Yammer JS SDK). So, I want get all the groups of a login-ed user.

**Inorder to get all the groups**, I have tried to call the end points in two ways, `/groups.json=mine` using **SDK** - `resposne showing method not authorised` and `www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json=mine=1` using normal ajax GET request- throwing access control origin issue.

API is perfectly working, while tested using google chrome browser - by disabling web security.

My question is how I can call **www.yammer.com/api/v1/API_END_POINTS** without ***cross origin issue*** using **yammer JS SDK** or any other technique?

I found an related answer in this [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111945/find-all-yammer-groups-on-the-network-perhaps-with-api)  , but still showing error for me.

**Error** :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json?mine=1. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://xxx.dev.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

**Code I have tried after login code :**

1# GET Request - `return $http.get('https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json?mine=1')`

2# yammer JS SDK -

```
yam.platform.request({
        url: "groups.json?mine=1",
        method: "GET",
        success: function (group) {
          console.log(group);
        },

        error: function (group) {
          console.error("There was an error with the request.", group);
        }
      });
```

I have already commented different Q&As for the opinion, but no luck, no one replied.

PS - My all other yammer APIs are working(login, post, message etc), which listed in Yammer REST API Docs, only I am facing problem with APIs hosted in **wwww.yammer.com/api/v1**, **Not** *api.yammer.com*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should register an App in Yammer dev console, specify allowed origins, get an API key and send it along with request.

See https://developer.yammer.com/docs/api-requests for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Issue is not related to auth or JS Origins.  API not giving response to `groups.json?mine=1` API using JS sdk, and calling get request directly showing access origin issue. All other yammer APIs are working .  I believe they are not hosted/given permission to `groups.json/` API in api.yammer.com, only in `www.yammer.com`.